# Force new Mobile IP

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, tethering

I'm using my droid phone, running KitKat, to wifi tether my linux box to the internet.  The application that I'm writing requires me change my ip address on occasion.  Is there a way that I can communicate with my phone, connected via USB, and force it to obtain a new mobile ip address?  Using a VPN is not an option...

Comment: This sounds like it would be dependent on your network.  Quite possibly even a full disconnect and reconnect would not renew your IP, since they might expect occasional service issues and keep your IP lease active.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is reduce the WiFi IP lease time to reduce the duration of time that an IP address is assigned to a device before a new one is assigned.

You could also manually assign an IP address from Settigns -> WiFi ->long hold the WiFi AP name -> Advanced settings and manually assign a IP.

Comment: I'm actually talking about the LTE connection, not the WIFI